# Can I isolate the function in this equation?

Tags: functions

I need help with an equation for a project I’m working on :

I need to isolate the function $f()$ in what follows so I can put it in a software like maple or wolfram.

I have a function $p$,  that monotonically decreases (the division at the end serves to normalize). 
$p= 0,1*e^{(-0.003x)}/p(0)$

The function that interest me, $f()$,  is informally given as follows: $f(0)=0$. At each time instant t, the function grows by $1%$ of the value of $p(t)$ minus the cumulative $f(t)$ so far.
For formally:
$\Delta f(t)/dt = 0.01*( p(t) - \int_0^t f(t) dt   ).$

where $\Delta f(t)/dt$ is the variation of function $f()$ at time $t$.

Is there any way to isolate the function $f(t)$ in this equation? Ideally, can it be stated only in terms of $p(t)$ instead of in a recursive manner?

Comment: Take the derivative wrt t

Comment: @Rafa  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

We should write

$$f'(t)=\frac{df(t)}{dt} = 0.01\cdot\left( p(t) - \int_0^t f(u) du   \right)$$

from which we obtain

$$\implies f''(t)= 0.01\cdot\left( p'(t) - f(t)  \right) \implies f''(t)-0.01\cdot f(t)=0.01\cdot p'(t)$$

that is a linear differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

Define $F(t)$ as the antiderivative of $f(t)$. Thus, the equation simplifies to
$$F''(t)=\frac{1}{100}(p(t)-\int_0^tf(t)dt)=\frac{1}{100}(p(t)-F(t)+F(0)).$$

Using $p(t)=e^{\frac{-3}{1000}t}$ (I assume this is what you meant), this simplifies down to
$$F''(t)=\frac{1}{100}(e^{\frac{-3}{1000}t}-F(t)+F(0)).$$

There are many techniques to solve this, but in the end we get
$$F(t)=F(0)+c_1\sin(\frac{t}{10})+c_2\cos(\frac{t}{10})+\frac{10000}{10009}e^{\frac{-3}{1000}t}$$

(I found this using [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dsolve(f%27%27(t)%3D1%2F100*exp(-3%2F1000*t)-1%2F100f(t)%2B1%2F100a))). Of course, we want $f(t)$ and not $F(t)$. Simply differentiating gives us
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{10}c_1\cos(\frac{t}{10})-\frac{1}{10}c_2\sin(\frac{t}{10})-\frac{30}{10009}e^{\frac{-3}{1000}t}.$$

Inputting $f(0)=0$, we find
$$0=f(0)=\frac{1}{10}c_1-\frac{30}{10009}\Rightarrow c_1=\frac{300}{10009}.$$

Unfortunately, we still need another constant and the most simplified equation for $f(t)$ we can get is
$$f(t)=\frac{30}{10009}\cos(\frac{t}{10})-C\sin(\frac{t}{10})-\frac{30}{10009}e^{\frac{-3}{1000}t}$$

for some constant $C$.

Comment: hmmm Maybe I'm going at this the worng way. Is there a way to state what I'm looking for :" f() grows as at a rate of 1% of  p() minus its own cumulative value" in a non-recursive manner that does not involve f()?

Comment: or, is there a reasonable way to approximate it?